why does my terminal freeze when i am trying to install something in the terminal through npm?
I am new to NodeJS , and while trying to download third party libraries, the terminal just freezes. If i restart the pc and run the command again, it directly starts downloading.
this is happening every time
PS D:\Node_js_folder\Express_Startup>  npm install --save body-parser
[..................] / idealTree:Express_Startup: sill idealTree buildDeps



PS D:\Node_js_folder\Express_Startup> npm install body-parser

up to date in 1m

16 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

Can anyone help identifying where is the problem occuring as restarting every time is very annoying.

The problem was arising due the the antivirus blocking downloads through npm manager . the best way to solve it was to simply remove the anti-virus application
